# How to extract files from Windows Vista Complete PC Backup?

Tags: windows, api, windows-vista, backup

Is there a program or API I can code against to extract individual files from a Windows Vista Complete PC Backup image?

I like the idea of having a complete image to restore from, but hate the idea that I have to make two backups, one for restoring individual files, and one for restoring my computer in the event of a catastrophic failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an API.  Windows Vista Complete PC Backup creates a .vhd (virtual hard disk) image that can be accessed via the [Virtual Server 2005 API](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756145.aspx) or from a command line utility available in Virtual Server 2005 which is freely available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualserver/default.aspx).

Comment: The tool that will satisfy my needs is VHDMount.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[7-Zip](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http://www.7-zip.org/&ei=9R1wTqmOJIqugQel9t2MBQ&usg=AFQjCNElgl3u-wgL-ZOjo_CH4znsHpsyyw&sig2=_n_0s3MDtdi3ZvKKxBcKtg) will open .vhd files of WindowsImageBackup...